# Can the useCallback React hook be used conditionally even if it breaks the rules of hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to **memoize React components** by specifying particular props.

For instance, if you use `React.memo` — it memoizes the component based on all props.

What I am trying to achieve is being able to pass particular props as a dependency to a util (say, `SuperMemo`) and the component will be memoized based on those props. The approach is very similar to what [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) — compose the component before export.

Here's an example code

```js
import React from "react";

const isFunction = value =>
  value &&
  (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Function]" ||
    "function" === typeof value ||
    value instanceof Function);

export const memo = (Comp, resolver) => {
  if (isFunction(resolver)) {
    const Memoized = props => {
      const deps = resolver(props);
      if (deps && deps.length) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
        return React.useCallback(React.createElement(Comp, props), deps);
      }

      return React.createElement(Comp, props);
    };

    Memoized.displayName = `memoized(${Comp.name})`;
    return Memoized;
  }

  return React.memo(Comp);
};

export default memo;
```

Here is how it will be used to compose components

```js
import Todo from "./Todo";
import memo from "../memo";

export default memo(Todo, props => [props.text]);
```

I have a working codesandbox here — [memo-deps](https://codesandbox.io/s/9ylw1xv1zr)

This is what I have observed —

- I should not use `React.useCallback` or any hook inside a conditional statement because React needs to know the order in which hooks are invoked and using it inside a conditional may mess up the order during runtime
- But `React.useCallback` works pretty neat in a conditional for my case as I know the order will remain the same during runtime
- I am not using the hook inside the conditional statement during render, instead I am composing the component during export conditionally
- I am thinking about React components as plain JavaScript functions and trying to memoize it like how I would memoize a regular JavaScript function
- I could easily replace `React.useCallback` with `lodash.memoize` and the end result will be pretty much the same
- I don't want to use an external library like `lodash.memoize` or build a custom implementation of memoization while `React.useCallback` pretty much does the work for me

This is where I am not sure what's happening (these are my questions) —

- React components are not really vanilla JavaScript functions and I cannot memoize them with `lodash.memoize`
- `lodash.memoize` and `React.useCallback` are not the same when I try to memoize a React component
- React executes the function before figuring out the render even when `React.memo` is used (maybe to check prevProps vs newProps?)
- Is my implementation okay even though it breaks the rules of React? (use hook in a conditional statement)
- How else can I memoize a `React.createElement` if not for `React.useCallback`?

The reason as to why I might want to do this —

*I don't want to memoize handlers (closure with a value and event) every time I pass them to a component wrapped in `React.memo`. I want to be able to declaratively write memoize dependencies for components.*

Comment: There's no 'outside a component' in the code you posted. useCallback is used inside Memoized component. And it's misused because `React.createElement(Comp, props)` is not a function.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong terminology. I meant that the `Memoized` is a wrapper over the real component and it is not affected by the render logic of the real component.

Comment: I was curious about `React.createElement(Comp, props)` as well. Should `useMemo` be used there instead of `useCallback`?

Comment: *it is not affected by the render logic of the real component* - this is the reason why it's acceptable and doesn't break the rules of hooks. It should be `React.useMemo(() => React.createElement(Comp, props), ...)` then. `React.useCallback(React.createElement(Comp, props), deps)` is workable but it's semantically incorrect and results in unnecessary createElement call.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question per se, but if you use Typescript, you don't have to waste time on implementing functions like `isFunction`.

Answer (score 6):

`React.memo` accepts a function as the second parameter to do a custom props comparison.

> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props
> object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide
> a custom comparison function as the second argument.

You can use that in your util function like this :

```
export const memoWithSecondParam = (Comp, deps = []) => {
  return React.memo(Comp, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return deps.every(d => prevProps[d] === nextProps[d])
  });
};
```

And call it like this :

```
export default memoWithSecondParam(Todo, ["text"]);
```

Comment: Is there anything like this for the `useMemo` hook?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question posed in the title "Can the useCallback React hook be used conditionally even if it breaks the rules of hooks?"

Comment: `useMemo` and `useCallback` are not really meant for memoizing component, they're used for simple values. `React.memo` in the other hand is used exactly for that.

Comment: Breaking the rules of hooks may work (like in you codesandbox), but it makes your code fragile, and may break in the future if the react team decide to change how things are implemented. I don't recommend that. If you find a solution that works using public APIs then stick with it